# What is triggering an 0x08 interrupt?

Tags: c, timer, linux-kernel, x86-64

I'm trying to hijack the Timer interrupt. A colleague told me that interrupt 0x08 on the IDT (Interrupt Descriptor Table) is the timer. Of curse I checked and saw two possible answers: [this](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/chap-Realtime_Reference_Guide-Hardware_interrupts.html) which says that 8 is the `real clock timer` and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table) saying it's the `Double Fault` interrupt - I decided to believe him and not waste time on checking further. After finally having control over the IDT and replacing interrupt 8, nothing is happening.

- So what is going on?
- Did this interrupt change its purpose over time from timer to double fault?
- Does this interrupt has different purposes on ARM/Intel/etc.?

My code is a kernel module, that hijacks the interrupt 8 and simply do a `printk` command every time the interrupt arrives. I ran it for about 25 minutes - No output in `dmesg`.

In case it matters: I run Linux Mint with kernel 3.8 on a VM. The host has an Intel i5.

Comment: Wouldn't the kernel already be using it to do process scheduling?

Comment: Probably - I was expecting a kernel crash for now, and later calling the original function from my function (proxying the original handler). But right now it seems that nothing happens.

Comment: @roe: On most modern kernels, the [APIC timer](http://wiki.osdev.org/APIC_timer) is used for that. Much more flexible and precise, and it's per-CPU instead of global.

Comment: @duskwuff, see, that's how long it's been since i did kernel scheduling work... :) I'm oooooold ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can find which interrupt is for timer by using this command: cat /proc/interrupt

Following is a sample output on a 6 core machine:

```
cat /proc/interrupts | egrep "timer|rtc"
   0:  320745126          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
   8:          1          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
 LOC:  115447297  304097630  194770704  212244137   63864376   69243268   Local timer interrupts
```

Note, timer and rtc are different. Also there is only one rtc interrupt so far. (Lots of timer interrupts). Following is the uptime output.

```
 uptime
 14:14:20 up 13 days,  3:58,  9 users,  load average: 0.47, 1.68, 1.38
```

I think you should check this before you hack IDT. Also, probably, you want to hack interrupt 0, not 8.

Answer (score 0):

You have found two descriptions for the same IRQ because in protected mode the address range 0x0 - 0x1F are reserved for internal cpu interruptions use.

You have to remap IRQs to another address space without conflicts, in this article you can find it explained with all the source code needed:

https://alfaexploit.com/readArticle/416